# Django: Problem with passing parameters from a template {% url %} to a view

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I have this urlpath:

```py
path('download/<str:fpath>/<str:fname>', views.download, name='download'),
```

And this is the view:

```py
def download(request, fpath, fname):
    # some code
```

In template, I have this href tag and I want to pass those strings as arguments to the `download` view.

```html
<a href="{% url 'download' 'lms/static/lms/files/homework/Math 1/3/3' 'hmm.pdf' %}">click me</a>
```

But I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'download' with arguments '('lms/static/lms/files/homework/Math 1/3/3', 'hmm.pdf')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/(?P<fpath>[^/]+)/(?P<fname>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried reducing space from first argument? Try `{% url 'download' 'x' 'y' %}` and see if you have different response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Url arguments of type `str` cannot contains `/` characters. You can see this in the error message which has translated your `<str:fpath>` to a regex:

```
tried: ['download/(?P<fpath>[^/]+)/(?P<fname>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

You should use a `path` converter for your case (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)).

For example:

```
path('download/<path:fpath>/<str:fname>', ...)
```